# Seeking optimised proper mysql query for multiple table joins

Tags: mysql, database

Hi developer/dba friends I have small issues for fetching details with mysql tables as following :

I have cid lets say `cid=xxx`

**I want output(cid,ruser_id,dtoken,akey,prase) in one record using cid as key input**

what mysql query I should perform that can also optimise this fetch with smooth less time on execution?

table structure is as following:

```
tbl_mk(cid,pro_id) -> pro_id primary key of tbl_pro

tbl_luser(cid,ruser_id) -> ruser_id primary key of tbl_ruser

tbl_ruser(id,dtoken)->id is primary key of this tbl_ruser where its referenced in tbl_luser as ruser_id

tbl_pro(id,akey)-> id is primary key of this tbl_pro which its referenced in tbl_mk as pro_id

tbl_app(akey,prase)
```

`primary id/reference` naming convention is i.e like if name of table is 
tbl_name then id referenced in other table for `tbl_name` is `name_id. where id is primary key of tbl_name`.

I know there are lot of mysql experts here so how to make it working with less efforts, fyi I am basically mobile app developer but there is time m working on some mysql stuffs for web apis needs :)

Thanks and I really appreciate and admire if some one can solve this problem for me.I did one query and getting details but seems its not proper way I need more efficient way thats why m posting here.

Waiting for some best reply with expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the tables. Assuming `:cid` is your input:

```
SELECT l.cid, l.ruser_id, r.dtoken, p.akey, prase
FROM   tbl_luser l
JOIN   tbl_ruser r ON l.ruser_id = r.id
JOIN   tbl_mk m ON l.cid = m.cid 
JOIN   tbl_pro p ON p.id = m.prod_id
JOIN   tbl_app a ON a.akey = p.akey
WHERE  l.cid = :cid
```

Comment: This query works for my purpose I appricate and thanks for the quick reply but only one problem @Mureinik that is it possible to get only one record without using 'Limit 1' in query as knowing by the fact that tbl_pro & tbl_app have tbl_app(one)<TO>tbl_pro(one) relation thats means akey will have only one record for pro_id joined with akey. its giving right now multiple records but identical.